# Elegant way to check item in an array of ranges

Tags: postgresql

About array of ranges (ex. `int4range[]`), and [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html).

Suppose table `t` as

```
CREATE TABLE t (id serial, r int4range[]); 
INSERT INTO t (r) VALUES 
  ('{"[2,5]","[100,200]"}'::int4range[]),
  ('{"[6,9]","[201,300]"}'::int4range[]);
```

So, to check if **7** or **70** are there,  need a query like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, unnest(r) as ur FROM t) t2  WHERE 7<@ur;  -- row2
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, unnest(r) as ur FROM t) t2  WHERE 70<@ur; -- empty
```

**There are a less ugly way to do this kind of queries?**

---

NOTE: need a generic "template" to build functions that returns the table with simple `*` query,

```
CREATE FUNCTION t_where(int4) RETURNS t AS $f$
   SELECT  id,r -- but need *   
   FROM ( SELECT *, unnest(r) as ur FROM t) t2 
   WHERE $1 <@ ur
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

So the same query is `SELECT * FROM t_where(7)`, 
but I need (an elegant way) to build using `*`, not listing fields (`id,r`).

Comment: `select t.* ...`?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name yes, `t.*`  but there are no `t` in the unnested context .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, you can use an implicit `LATERAL JOIN`, giving  you access to `t.*` in the main `SELECT`:

```
#= SELECT t.*
   FROM t, unnest(r) AS ur
   WHERE 7<@ur;
┌────┬────────────────────────┐
│ id │           r            │
├────┼────────────────────────┤
│  2 │ {"[6,10)","[201,301)"} │
└────┴────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```